# Webrtc's occasional black screen on Google Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, webrtc, screen

Using Windows to project screen on Google Chrome, occasional black screen。The outbound-rtp of the video is sent as 0, but the audio is sent normally, Do you have any troubleshooting ideas for this situation? Coding or network broadband issues?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oagyI.png)

I hope to be able to project the screen normally

Comment: The video stream for screen projection is normal, with sound and visuals when pulled down